# Why run_app() in {golem} starts the shiny app?

Tags: shiny, golem

The `run_app()` function in **{golem}** returns an object of class `shiny.appobj`, as far as I understand, since this is what is returned by `with_golem_options()` with the default parameter `print=FALSE`, inside `run_app()`. How does this object get "printed", i.e. the app executed?

I do not see any difference in calling `with_golem_options()` with `print=FALSE` or `print=TRUE`. In both cases, the shiny app starts normally.